# autocomplete multicolumn does not work

Tags: jquery

i have a seb service, here the code:

```
<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False, XmlSerializeString:=False)>
Public Function Names(ByVal a As String) As String
    Dim nomi()() As String = New String(2)() {}
    nomi(0) = New String() {"Windows", "IIS", "AspNet"}
    nomi(1) = New String() {"Linux", "Apache", "PHP"}
    nomi(2) = New String() {"Xml", "Soap", "JSon"}
    Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim strJSon As String = js.Serialize(nomi)
    Return strJSon
End Function
```

:

```js
$("#search2").mcautocomplete({
            showHeader: true,
            columns: columns,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url: 'http:\\applicazioni.vsc300.it/Service.asmx/Names")',
                    data: "{ 'a': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                
                }
                )}
                });
             




        function customRenderItem(ul, item) {
            var t = '<span class="mcacCol1">' + item[0] + '</span><span class="mcacCol2">' + item[1] + '</span>',
    result = $('<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"></li>')
    .data('item.autocomplete', item)
    .append('<a class="ui-corner-all" style="position:relative;" tabindex="-1">' + t + '</a>')
    .appendTo(ul);
            return result;
        }
        var columns = [{name: 'Color', minWidth: '100px'}, {name: 'Hex', minWidth:'70px'}],
   colors = [['Red', '#f00'], ['Green', '#0f0'], ['Blue', '#01f']];


        $("#search").mcautocomplete({
         showHeader: true,
         columns: columns,
         source: colors,
         select: function(event, ui) {
          this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[0]: '');
          return false;
         }
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.19/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://applicazioni.vsc300.it/Scripts/jquery.mcautocomplete.js"></script>




<div style="margin:10px 10px;padding:8px;width:300px;" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
   <div style="margin:0 0 9px 4px;">Type in a color</div>
   
   <!-- This is the input control that gets turned into the jquery ui widget -->
   <input id="search" type="text" style="padding:12px;font-size:.8em;width:200px;"/>
  </div>

        search by service
        <input id="search2" type="text" style="padding:12px;font-size:.8em;width:200px;"/>
```

that returns some strings, but i want to use in my page with multicolumn autocomplete
as you can see, the first autocomplete is OK, the second one, that should call the service does not work

Comment: I got a question, in search2, the source anonim function shouldn't return the `done` or `success` ajax response?  `$('input[name="q"]').autoComplete({source: function(term, response){$.getJSON('/some/ajax/url/', { q: term }, function(data){response(data); });}});` __[AJAX requests](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)__

Comment: i have a test page in my web site that has it: http://applicazioni.vsc300.it/prova.aspx

Comment: the console report: __Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '74' in [["Windows","IIS","AspNet"],["Linux","Apache","PHP"],["Xml","Soap","JSon"]]__

Comment: thanks Diego, after your advice i updated the code...i need the last advice now...i have no idea what the error is